# gsub across each row of multiple columns of dataframe R

Tags: regex, r

I have a sample data frame as shown below:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Col1= c("a woman's hat 9 in. long", "ABC company news", "P.F.Chang's house", "this would weigh 90 lbs."),
Col2= c("9 in.", "ABC", "P.F.Chang's", "90 lbs."),
stringsAsFactors=F)

dat1
                      Col1        Col2
1 a woman's hat 9 in. long       9 in.
2         ABC company news         ABC
3        P.F.Chang's house P.F.Chang's
4 this would weigh 90 lbs.     90 lbs.
```

I would like to remove part of col1 that matches with col2 of the data frame. So, I want the result as follows:

```
                Col1        Col2
1 a woman's hat long       9 in.
2       company news         ABC
3              house P.F.Chang's
4   this would weigh     90 lbs.
```

I tried `gsub(dat1$col2, '', dat1$col1)`. However, this would only use first element of dat1$col2 as the pattern.

Appreciate any inputs to get the results

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `stringr` package, and an edit suggested by **Nicola** -`fixed(dat1$col2)`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(dat1$Col1, fixed(dat1$Col2), "")

"a woman's hat  long" " company news"       " house"              "this would weigh "  
>
```

Comment: Nice one. I guess the pattern should be `fixed(dat1$Col2)`, otherwise characters like `.` will be interpreted incorrectly (and maybe `str_replace_all` should be used).

Comment: Thanks for teaching the `fixed` function. With the `replace_all` I'll leave that to the OP to think about :)

Comment: Thanks Max and Nicola! that was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

We can `paste` the elements in 'Col2' together, use that as `pattern` in `gsub`, in the replacement we use `''`, and remove the leading/lagging spaces with `trimws`.

```
dat1$col1 <- trimws(gsub(paste(dat1$Col2, collapse='|'), 
                '', dat1$Col1))
dat1$col1
#[1] "a woman's hat  long" "company news"        "house"               "this would weigh"
```

---

We could also use `stri_replace`

```
library(stringi)
stri_trim(stri_replace(dat1$Col1, fixed=dat1$Col2, ""))
#[1] "a woman's hat  long" "company news"        "house"               "this would weigh"
```

---

A much more compact approach would be

```
library(qdap)
with(dat1, mgsub(Col2, '', Col1))
#[1] "a woman's hat long" "company news"       "house"              "this would weigh"
```

Comment: This may have 2 undesired effects. The first happens if a pattern in a row is present in another row. It will be (incorrectly) deleted. The second is that you cannot use `fixed=TRUE` in the regex, since there is the pipe. But "9 inX" will match the first pattern and get replaced.

Comment: @nicola I understand that there would be problems.  My regex is based on the example showed.

Comment: @nicola I meant your comment as if my answer is wrong.